# Including the Gurobi libary in C++

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, gurobi

I am currently trying to include the Gurobi library in my C++ project.
I am using CLion as my IDE, so I changed the `CMakeLists.txt` into:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test_gurobi)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories("/opt/gurobi951/linux64/include")

add_executable(test_gurobi main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test_gurobi "/opt/gurobi951/linux64/lib/libgurobi95.so")
target_link_libraries(test_gurobi "/opt/gurobi951/linux64/lib/libgurobi_c++.a")
```

This seems to me like it should work. However, following minimal example

```
#include "gurobi_c++.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    GRBEnv env = GRBEnv(true);
    return 0;
}
```

as my `main.cpp` yields the following error when compiled:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/gurobi951/linux64/lib/libgurobi_c++.a(Env.o): in function `GRBEnv::~GRBEnv()':
Env.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `GRBfreeenv'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/gurobi951/linux64/lib/libgurobi_c++.a(Env.o): in function `GRBEnv::getErrorMsg() const':
Env.cpp:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `GRBgeterrormsg'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/gurobi951/linux64/lib/libgurobi_c++.a(Env.o): in function `GRBEnv::GRBEnv(bool)':
Env.cpp:(.text+0xe3): undefined reference to `GRBemptyenvadv'
/usr/bin/ld: Env.cpp:(.text+0x18a): undefined reference to `GRBloadenvadv'
/usr/bin/ld: Env.cpp:(.text+0x1ae): undefined reference to `GRBfreeenv'

.
.
.

Env.cpp:(.text+0x15c4): undefined reference to `GRBwriteparams'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/gurobi951/linux64/lib/libgurobi_c++.a(Env.o): in function `GRBEnv::readParams(std::string const&)':
Env.cpp:(.text+0x1674): undefined reference to `GRBreadparams'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/gurobi951/linux64/lib/libgurobi_c++.a(Env.o): in function `GRBEnv::message(std::string const&)':
Env.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `GRBmsg'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_gurobi.dir/build.make:106: test_gurobi] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/test_gurobi.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: CMakeFiles/test_gurobi.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:138: test_gurobi] Error 2
```

Does anyone see why my code doesn't compile? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the official CMake files for C/C++ projects provided by Gurobi: [How do I use CMake to build Gurobi C/C++ projects?](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039499751-How-do-I-use-CMake-to-build-Gurobi-C-C-projects-)

This guide includes a `FindGUROBI.cmake` as well as a `CMakeLists.txt` example.